# Is it possible to create a vector of concept ? std::vector<Concept auto>

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to study the concept functionality and syntax, but I failed to come up with a working example of std::vector, any idea of what is going wrong ?
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/FHaQ-3

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
concept Compare = requires(T a, T b) {
    { a <=> b } -> std::same_as<std::partial_ordering>;
};

struct Cat {
    int age;
    std::string name;
    auto operator<=>(const Cat&) const = default;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /* Single type: Fail
    std::vector<Compare auto> vec{
        Cat{4, "Faisca"},
        Cat{4, "Neka"}
    };

    */
    /* Heterogenous: Fail
    std::vector<Compare auto> vec{
        Cat{4, "Faisca"}, 1, std::string{"Deu Ruim"}
    };
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a vector of heterogenous types, that satisfy a concept?

Comment: Vectors hold one type. You have to pick one single type that can hold any of those values.

Comment: yes, I'm aiming to have a vector of heterogenous types that has a concept, or a vector of a single type, I'm failing in both scenarios.

Comment: The first is not possible. The second should be(i,e. a vector whose type must satisfy a concept), but edit your question to show what you've tried for that.

Comment: If you have the time to invest, [this video](https://youtu.be/OtU51Ytfe04?t=5172) goes in-depth on techniques to implement this sort of type erasure. The link is to a timestamp with something very similar to the code in your question on the slide, but the majority of the talk discusses his actual solution, with this last part being focused on possible future language changes to enable simpler-to-use libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a `std::vector` of heterogenous types.

However, you can have a `std::vector` of type `T` that satisfies a concept. Simply provide a alias template that is constrained:

```
template<typename T>
 requires Compare<T>
  using vec = std::vector<T>;
```

or with terse syntax:

```
template<Compare T>
 using vec = std::vector<T>;
```

Now, you can do:

```
vec<Cat> v;
```

but not

```
vec<int> v;
```

Note that your `Cat` class as currently written, doesn't *actually* satisfy the concept `Compare`. If you change the return type of `operator<=>`, like this:

```
std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const Cat&) const = default;
```

you can create a vector of `Cat`s:

```
vec<Cat> a{
   Cat{4, "Faisca"},
   Cat{4, "Neka"}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for informing that, but it does not shows the usage of `std::vector<Concept auto>`.

Comment: It does, conceptually, if I understand your intent. It's just that the syntax is not correct. What *is* the intent of `std::vector<Concept auto>`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use placeholder types (`auto` and `decltype(auto)`, with or without constraints) within template argument lists like that. You must either use a concrete type or rely on class template argument deduction from C++17 (by not specifying template arguments at all).

A `vector<T>` is a sequence container, and sequence containers contain objects of a given type. A *single* given type.